# ASP.NET CORE 2.0 runtime value using DI

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

In ASP.NET CORE 2.0, how can I pass runtime parameter(string type) such as dynamic connection string to my service as Dependency injection. The string parameter value will be dynamic and be taken from HttpContext.

I'm not able to understand how can I pass runtime parameter value using DI from Controller->Service->Repository class?

Below code is what I'm using. Please guide me.

### Code

```
public class AccountController : BaseController//Controller
    {
        ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
         private IUserService _userService;
        public AccountController(
            ILogger<AccountController> logger
           , IUserService userService
            ) {
            _logger = logger;
            _userService = userService;
        }


 public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private readonly IRoleRepository _roleRepository;
        public UserService(
            IUserRepository userRepository
            ,IRoleRepository roleRepository
            )
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _roleRepository = roleRepository;
        }

 public class UserRepository : DbProvider, IUserRepository
    {
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private DatabaseSetting _databaseSetting;
        public UserRepository(IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<DatabaseSetting> databaseSetting) : base(configuration, databaseSetting)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _databaseSetting = databaseSetting.Value;


        }

public static class StartupExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddCloudscribeCore(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {

            // Add application repository.
            services.AddSingleton<AuthAttributeFilter>();

            #region Add Repository Dependency Here
            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();
            #endregion Repository Dependency

            #region Add Service Dependency Here
            services.AddTransient<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
            services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();



            #endregion Service Dependency

            services.Configure<DatabaseSetting>(options =>
            {
                options.DBProvider = configuration["DatabaseSetting:DBProvider"];
                options.ConnectionString = configuration["DatabaseSetting:ConnectionString"];


            });
            return services;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing `HttpContext` in `Service` and `Repository`, there is no need to pass from Controller, try `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```
    public class UserRepository : DbProvider, IUserRepository
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    private DatabaseSetting _databaseSetting;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public UserRepository(IConfiguration configuration, IOptions<DatabaseSetting> databaseSetting, IHttpContextAccessor accessor) : base(configuration, databaseSetting)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _databaseSetting = databaseSetting.Value;
        _accessor = accessor;
 }
```

Then, you could access `HttpContext` by `_accessor.HttpContext`.